# Diamond-shaped dependency in JBoss applications

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, maven-2

I have two JBoss applications that inter-operates and have a common dependency: application A creates an object of class contained in the common dependency, then passes this object to application B. When I try to use some object's method in application B, a runtime exception is thrown: either `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` if the dependency is packed solely in A's deploy unit, or `java.lang.LinkageError` if I pack the dependency in both deploy units.

Using Maven2 as build system, how can I solve this problem? I assume I must make both application load dependency's classes from a single jar, how to do it?

Comment: passes how exactly, are yuo using s @remote method or something else?

Comment: JAIN SLEE 1.1 (JSR 240) event: one application is the Resource Adaptor, the other is the Service Building Block. The application server is the JBoss shipped with Mobicents JAIN SLEE implementation.